# How to ref stargazer tables in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, stargazer

It seems that stargazer tables cannot be referenced in RMarkdown anymore.

I have *unsuccessfully* tried to implement the workarounds posted on the github page that refer to this problem https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/175

````
---
title: "Ref Stargazer Test"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results='asis'}
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)
stargazer::stargazer(m1, type = "html", label = "tab:model")
```

Table \@ref(tab:model) should show something on cars.

```{r mytab, results="asis"}
stargazer::stargazer(attitude,
type=ifelse(knitr::is_latex_output(),"latex","html"),
label=knitr::opts_current$get("label"),
title="Stargazer <3 Bookdown")
```

As Table \@ref(tab:mytab) shows, relationships may be hard work but love finds a way.
````

The referencing does not work as of July 2021 (rmarkdown 2.9, bookdown 0.22, stargazer 5.2.2).

Is there another workaround that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution myself that works for LaTeX and HTML.

````
---
title: "Ref Stargazer Test"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

Table \@ref(tab:mytable) is the referenced table.

```{r mytable, results='asis', fig.cap="This is my table."}
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)

# Use title caption from fig.cap
tit <- knitr::opts_current$get("fig.cap")

# Adding caption for html output
tit_html <- paste0('<span id="tab:',
                   knitr::opts_current$get("label"),
                   '">(#tab:',
                   knitr::opts_current$get("label"),
                   ')</span>',
                   tit)

stargazer::stargazer(m1,
                     label = paste0("tab:", knitr::opts_current$get("label")),
                     title = ifelse(knitr::is_latex_output(), tit, tit_html),
                     type = ifelse(knitr::is_latex_output(),"latex","html"),
                     header = F
                     )
```
````

You can now also use the `fig.cap` argument in the chunk header to write the title you want to have for your table. For referencing, you have to refer to the chunk label (in this case "mytable"). The `title` argument in `stargazer` creates the `<caption>` element, this is why the html title is inserted there.

Comment: This is a helpful solution! Works perfectly (:

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of solving this is by adding manually your table's name on `stargazer`.

```
label = "tab:table4"
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
stargazer(m1, label = "tab:mytable")
```

And now you will be able to cross reference as usual in Rmarkdown `\ref{tab:mytable}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve this with `stargazer`. I will note that `bookdown` cross-references are a pretty recent feature, and that `stargazer` has not been updated in over 3 years, so issues are bound to arise.

One more modern alternative is [the `modelsummary` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (disclaimer: I am the maintainer). In my biased opinion, this package is more flexible and robust, but YMMV.

Below I paste a minimal example of Rmarkdown document with cross-references. A couple things to note:

- `modelsummary` detects the output format automatically, so you only need to specify LaTeX or HTML in the YAML header at the very top of your Rmarkdown document. No need to use the `output` argument of `modelsummary` (but check out the documentation anyway!).
- The table label is set by the name of the chunk. Here, it is called "model", so we use `tab:model` as a cross-reference.
- Your table needs a title, otherwise cross-references won't show up consistently.

````
---
title: "modelsummary cross-reference test"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

```{r model}
library(modelsummary)

m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)

modelsummary(m1, title = "A table title")
```

Table \@ref(tab:model) should show something on cars.
````

Comment: Thank you! Not exactly what I was looking for, but interesting package. Maybe it is a good idea to switch, since stargazer is not actively developed anymore. However, I have one question: Is there a way to output latex instead of html like it's done with the `type` argument in stargazer (not as a separate file)?

Comment: Yes, look at the documentation for the "output" argument. There are a ton of possible formats.